# Cant get SoundCloud API to play without autoStarting

Tags: javascript, api, soundcloud

this Code worked to play/pause the song, but i couldnt get it to stop autoplaying on page load.

```
function play_pause() {
      SC.stream( "/tracks/156709825", function(sound) {
        var is_playing = true;
        sound.play();
        document.getElementById("play_1").onclick = function(){  
          if(is_playing === false){
            sound.resume();
            is_playing = true;
          } else if(is_playing === true){
            sound.pause();
            is_playing = false;
          }  
        };                                  
      });
    }
    play_pause();

<button  onclick="play_pause();" id="play_1">Play</button>
```

But I did some refactoring and got rid of the onclick, and tried to fix the problem, and i refs the soundcloud API doc to create this format : `SC.stream(trackPath, [options], [callback])`

```
function startStream() {
        SC.stream("/tracks/156709825", {
            autoPlay: false,
            onready: function (sound) {
                var is_playing = true;

                function playPause() {
                    if (is_playing) {
                        sound.pause();
                        is_playing = false;
                    } else {
                        sound.resume();
                        is_playing = true;
                    }
                }

                sound.play();
                var play_button = document.getElementById("play_1");
                play_button.addEventListener("click", playPause, false);
            }
        });
    }
    startStream();
```

This time nothing worked, .. it onready was not getting called, so i decided to used the third argument.

```
function startStream() {
        console.log('starting stream');

        SC.stream("/tracks/156709825",
            {autoPlay: false},
            function (sound) {
                console.log('stream ready');

                var is_playing = true;
                sound.play();

                function togglePause() {
                    console.log('pause toggled');

                    if (is_playing) {
                        sound.pause();
                        is_playing = false;
                    } else {
                        sound.resume();
                        is_playing = true;
                    }

                    console.log('is_playing now', is_playing);
                }

                var play_button = document.getElementById("play_1");
                play_button.addEventListener("click", togglePause, false);
            }
        );
    }
    startStream();
```

This plays, but still auto starts, if anyone has any clue I would greatly appreciate it.

I have a couple fiddles, .. but i dont know how to hide my client_id.. soo i dont feel comfortable posting them here

Answer (score 0):

i found a workaround hack, but im certain it is not the correct way to handle this, .. I was never able to get the `autoPlay: false` option to work, .. so I just let it sound.play(), and then immediatly sound.pause(), .. and then change the is_playing state to start off as false

```
function startStream() {
  console.log('starting stream');

  SC.stream("/tracks/156709825", { 
    autoPlay: false },

    function (sound) {
      console.log('stream ready');

      var is_playing = false;
      sound.play();
      sound.pause();

      function togglePause() {
        console.log('pause toggled');

        if (is_playing) {
            sound.pause();
            is_playing = false;
        } else {
            sound.resume();
            is_playing = true;
        }

        console.log('is_playing now', is_playing);
      }
    var play_button = document.getElementById("play_1");
    play_button.addEventListener("click", togglePause, false);
  });
}
startStream();
```

if you know of something a bit cleaner and better ide love to see it!